# javascript Isolating characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of characters and want to isolate 2 characters.

Isolate a or b from string:

"a48y jvu5agbl=dbz'bk;ahc"

Should get something like this:

aabbba

This regex gets me the correct result and whatever's left. How do I chop off the end?

```
str.replace(/.*?(b|a)/g,"$1");
```

Thanks. Any other way to isolate the characters is great too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have an easier time with `[^...]` to grab everything but and remove it:

```
str.replace(/[^ab]+/g, '');
```